# Map JS object and merge parameters into sub-object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm having difficulty with mapping over a JS object and merging data from one parameter into a sub-object of another parameter.

Suppose I have the following JSON:

```
const data = [
  {
    "difficulty": "Easy",
    "levels": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "Training",
        "description": "First training level."
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Story",
        "description": "First story level."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "difficulty": "Medium",
    "levels": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Training",
        "description": "First training level at medium difficulty."
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And I want to manipulate this to return:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Training",
    "description": "First training level.",
    "difficulty": "Easy"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Story",
    "description": "First story level.",
    "difficulty": "Easy"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Training",
    "description": "First training level at medium difficulty.",
    "difficulty": "Medium"
  }
];
```

I've tried:

```
const result = data.map(item => {
  const { difficulty, levels } = item;
  return levels.map(level => ({ ...level, difficulty }));
});
```

But I end up with:

```
[
   [
      {
         "id": 0,
         "title": "Training",
         "description": "First training level.",
         "difficulty": "Easy"
      },
      {
         "id": 1,
         "title": "Story",
         "description": "First story level.",
         "difficulty": "Easy"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id": 2,
         "title": "Training",
         "description": "First training level at medium difficulty.",
         "difficulty": "Medium"
      }
   ]
]
```

I only want to return all `levels` with `difficulty` added in.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you use nested .map functions. Each .map function returns an array. To avoid it you can use .flat() method to reduce nesting
Your solution can be transformed into this

```
const result = data.map(item => {
      const { difficulty, levels } = item;
      return levels.map(level => ({ ...level, difficulty }));
      }).flat();
```

By default, it compresses for 1 nested array. 
More info you can find here: [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

But be careful to use this for huge collections of data, because it iterates over array so it can reduce performance.

UPD
Kind of solution without .map method

```
function mapDifficultyToLevels(data) {
  const result = []
  data.forEach(item => {
    item.levels.forEach(level => {
      result.push({
        difficulty: item.difficulty,
        ...level
      })
    })
  })
  return result
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks @andy-s ! Hmm I see there's also a `flatMap` too.

Since I'm using two nested `map` functions, would it be best to instead change one of them?

Comment: @dan2k3k4 In any case, you will need to iterate over all arrays, but at the same time you have the possibility to control the level of nesting at the output. I think you may use forEach method to iterate over array and sub array too. I've update the answer with example.

Answer (score 0):

Using map iterate through the levels array and add difficulty property and use flat() to remove nested arrays and flatten into one array.

```js
const data = [{"difficulty": "Easy", "levels": [{"id": 0,"title": "Training","description": "First training level."},{"id": 1,"title": "Story","description": "First story level."}] },{"difficulty": "Medium","levels": [ {"id": 2, "title": "Training","description": "First training level at medium difficulty."}]}];
let result=data.map( obj =>obj.levels.map(level=>{
level["difficulty"]=obj.difficulty;return level}
)).flat();
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```